# Finding the 20th percentile pixel of an image using a histogram instead of std::sort

Tags: c++, performance, image, statistics, opencv

I have a 2-dimensional matrix (an image) in which I need to find the 20th percentile value.  My first attempt was to sort the values and then index using `std::floor(0.2*(srcSor.size())/100)`.

My code was originally straightforward like this:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
   //Read the image .jpeg
   cv::Mat src=cv::imread(argv[1], CV_8UC1);
   std::vector<double> srcSor = src.reshape(0, 1); 
   std::sort (srcSor.begin(), srcSor.end(), std::greater<double>());  
   float A = srcSor[std::floor(0.2*(srcSor.size())/100)];
   //Then later I use A value..
   .
   .

   return 0;
}
```

I found that `std::sort` took a long time to sort a vector of 1.3m unsigned values.
So now I'm using an histogram to do the same thing; this takes less time to find that value of that certain index. The idea comes from the fact that the values of the matrix are `unsigned int` in the range 0-255:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
   //Read the image .jpeg
   cv::Mat src=cv::imread(argv[1], CV_8UC1);

   std::vector<unsigned> histo(256,0.0);
   for(unsigned j=0;j<src.rows;j++)
      for(unsigned i=0;i<src.cols;i++)
          histo[(int)src.at<uchar>(j,i)]++;

   std::vector<unsigned> sumHH(256,0.0);
   sumHH[255]=histo[255];
   for(unsigned i=254;i>=1;i--)
        sumHH[i]=sumHH[i+1]+histo[i];

   int A=0;
   int indx=std::floor(0.2*(src.rows*src.cols)/100);            
   for(unsigned i=1;i<255;i++)
     if(indx<sumHH[255-i])
     {
        A=255-i;
        break;  
     }
   //Then later I use A value..
   .
   .

   return 0;
}
```

But I think that my code is not really readable, can anyone suggest a better way to write my code and/or better optimized?

Comment: It looks like `std::nth_element` will be a better fit, if the function is invoked rarely.

Comment: 20th percentile should be only * 0.2 or 20/100. having both 0.2 and /100 gives the 0.2 percentile. Or have I misunderstood? @Ja_cpp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Well, `index=std::floor(0.2*(srcSor.size())/100` is equivalent to the much simpler `index = srcSor.size() / 500`, ignoring some inaccuracy in representing `0.2`.
2. Lose the fixed-size `std::vector`s. You don't depend on any of the benefits of using dynamic memory, so a simple array is sufficient and far more efficient.
3. Next, you really don't need the cumulative counts in `sumHH` at all. Just test whether you have reached the target immediately.
4. Don't cast unless you have to. Casting means overriding the type-system, and is thus error-prone.
5. Don't use obscure abbreviations.

Resulting code:

```
unsigned histogram[256] = {};
for (auto j = src.rows; j--;)
    for (auto i = src.cols; i--;)
        ++histogram[src.at<uchar>(j,i)];
int A = 255;
for (auto index = src.rows * src.cols / 500; index > histogram[A]; --A)
    index -= histogram[A];
```